# How to handle POST request using express in Node.js? I have written following code which is not working

Tags: node.js, express

Not able to handle post request data using express in Node.js. I want to handle form data from index.html file in test.js file. Getting error:
POST /test" Error (404): "Not found"

Following is the code which I have written:

index.html

```
<html>
    <body>
            <form action="/test" method="POST">
                Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var urlEncodedParser = app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: false
}));
app.post('/test',urlEncodedParser, function(req,res){
console.log("Kushagra "+req.body);
});
app.listen(8080,function(){
  console.log("Started in port 8080");
});
```

What to be done in order to receive form data from index.html file to test.js file.

Comment: how are you serving index.html? it doesn't look like you have any code to render html which makes me think it's on your filesystem or some other server

Answer (score 1):

`// TODO: Place this code before route & put index.html to public directory`

`const path = require("path");`

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));`